# Count how many check boxes are checked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Im trying to do this. I need to know how many check boxes are checked in mysql data base. The user consult a list from mysql data base that has check boxes and i need to indicate in some way how many are checked.

I have this code of the check box:

```
input <?php if (!(strcmp($row_List['Delivered'],1))) {echo "checked=\"checked\"";} ?> type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" />"]
```

Im expecting to receive `"Total Records Checked: (number)"`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: With this notation, your PHP script will always receive only one value. use `name="check[ SOME ID HERE ]"` to make an array (id should be self explanatory)

Comment: You need to know the number checked when displaying the form or after you submit it?  Show your loop that displays the checkboxes.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You probably can do it using javascript on the change event of checkbox.

```
alert(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
```

Of course if you have other checkboxs you would need to use another filter to get those you want to count.